# Error 1064 while inserting values

Tags: mysql

```
create table Eaddress (
    employeeid varchar(10), 
    building varchar(10), 
    street varchar(10), 
    city char(10), 
    district varchar(10), 
    state char(10), 
    phoneno int(10), 
    primary key(employeeid)
);

insert into Eaddress('P0001','N21','Avenue 12','NYC','D21','New York',6965269);
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''P0001','N21','Avenue 12','NYC','D21','New York',6965269)' at line 1

I am puzzled by this error. I Tried changing the values and altering the data types of columns but nothing worked.

Comment: @jophab Want to borrow my glasses!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope i already have one Thanks :). Sorry about that one.

Comment: @jophab No problem, just could not resist the joke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using  this sintax

```
insert into Eaddress 
values ('P0001','N21','Avenue 12','NYC','D21','New York', 6965269);
```

Comment: that was a terrible mistake ! i forgot to add "values" after the table name. 
it worked !
Thank you :o